# Flink job distribution over cluster nodes

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have 4 jobs that are running over 3 nodes with 4 slots per each,

On Flink 1.3.2 the jobs were evenly distributed per node.
After upgrading to flink 1.5 , each job is running on a single node (with a carry over to another if there are no slots left)

Is there a way to return to an even distribution? 
The jobs are not evenly by load which cause some nodes to work harder than other.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why does it matter if certain nodes have an higher load? In theory if you define the number of slots correctly you won't be over allocating work therefore it doesn't hurt performance. It seems that you have too many nodes for the parallelism you're using.

Comment: I have 4 different jobs ,for example  job 1 with 3 parallelism is running on task manager 1 ,job 2 with half the load and  same parallelism is running on task manager 2 , task manage 1 will use double the amount of resource (CPU/memory) than task manage 2 , while in flink 1.3.2 ,all task managers had used the same amount of resources because the jobs were distributed on all task managers (one per task manager)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer I received from flink mailing list 
[Re: Flink 1.5 job distribution over cluster nodes](http://apache-flink-mailing-list-archive.1008284.n3.nabble.com/Flink-1-5-job-distribution-over-cluster-nodes-td23364.html)

> Hi Shachar,
>
> with Flink 1.5 we added resource elasticity. This means that Flink is
>   now  able to allocate new containers on a cluster management framework
>   like Yarn  or Mesos. Due to these changes (which also apply to the
>   standalone mode),  Flink no longer reasons about a fixed set of
>   TaskManagers because if needed  it will start new containers (does not
>   work in standalone mode). Therefore,  it is hard for the system to
>   make any decisions about spreading slots  belonging to a single job
>   out across multiple TMs. It gets even harder when  you consider that
>   some jobs like yours might benefit from such a strategy  whereas
>   others would benefit from co-locating its slots. It gets even more 
>   complicated if you want to do scheduling wrt to multiple jobs which
>   the  system does not have full knowledge about because they are
>   submitted  sequentially. Therefore, Flink currently assumes that slots
>   requests can be  fulfilled by any TaskManager.
>
> Cheers,  Till